# Store user details in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The user logs in. The user can belong to many different ServiceAreas I am attempting to try and store the user's details in a `Session` that holds all the information for the user. The `foreach` keeps going round and errors when it tries to add the same `key`. That is my first error.

Q1. How will i stop this from happening.

Q2. Will I be able to store the users details in the `Session` whether they belong to 4 serviceAreas or 1?

```
var user = (from u in db.tbl_UserServiceAreaDetails
        where u.tbl_User.UserName.Equals(txt_LoginName.Text)
        && u.tbl_User.Password.Equals(txt_Password.Text)
        select u).FirstOrDefault();

if (user != null)
{
var serviceAreaID = user.serviceAreaID;
var serviceArea = user.tbl_ServiceArea.ServiceArea;

UserClass userDetails = new UserClass();

userDetails.UserName = user.tbl_User.UserName;

foreach (var item in serviceArea)
{
    userDetails.ServiceArea.Add(serviceAreaID, serviceArea);                
}
Session["User"] = userDetails;
```

`UserClass`

```
class UserClass
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> ServiceArea = new Dictionary<int, string>();
}
```

Do I need to do an `if item. Something` for Q1?

Comment: What is the error?  Key already exists?

Comment: yes it keeps going round the loop

Comment: why are you iterating over serviceArea without using the iterated value?

Comment: you tell us: how *would* we know how many service-areas the user is mapped to? by the fact that user has a single `serviceAreaID`, that says to me: they have exactly one (or maybe 0-or-1); also: storing plain-text passwords? really? in 2013?

Comment: Cause i dont know what that is ? I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You need your key to unique!

You cannot use Service Area ID as a key as it isn't unique

> "The user can belong to many different ServiceAreas"

How about in `UserClass` creating the following:

```
class UserClass
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, ServiceArea> ServiceAreaDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ServiceArea>();
}
```

Create a new class caled ServiceArea to store your information about Service Areas.

```
class ServiceArea
{
    public int ServiceAreaID { get; set; }
    public string ServiceAreaName { get; set; }

    public ServiceArea(int id, string name) {
      ServiceAreaID = id;
      ServiceAreaName = name
    }
}
```

Then...

```
var user = (from u in db.tbl_UserServiceAreaDetails
        where u.tbl_User.UserName.Equals(txt_LoginName.Text)
        && u.tbl_User.Password.Equals(txt_Password.Text)
        select u).FirstOrDefault();

      if (user != null)
        {
        var serviceAreaID = user.serviceAreaID;
        var serviceArea = user.tbl_ServiceArea.ServiceArea;

        UserClass userDetails = new UserClass();

        userDetails.UserName = user.tbl_User.UserName;

        foreach (var item in serviceArea)
        {
            userDetails.ServiceAreaDictionary.Add([SOME UNIQUE KEY HERE], new ServiceArea(serviceAreaID, serviceArea));                
        }
        Session["User"] = userDetails;
```

I hope this would solve your problem or give you an idea where to go next.

This method should allow you to check the `ServiceAreaDictionary` to find out what you want about a user. (i.e. how many areas they are members of etc)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean its the Service Area where the error is being generated?

If this is the case, its easy enough to fix BECAUSE you ONLY have 4 service areas.

Firtsly define your service areas in an ENUMERATION

```
Public Enum ServiceAreasEnum As Integer
  AreaN = 1 ' north
  AreaE = 2 ' East
  AreaS = 4 ' South
  AreaW = 8 ' West
End Enum
```

Now when a user is able to service more than ONE area you simply ADD the VALUES so a user servicing the NORTH and EAST would total to 3 and using that RULE You may fill in the other missing ENUM values

```
Public Enum ServiceAreasEnum As Integer
  AreaN = 1   ' NORTH
  AreaE = 2   ' EAST
  AreaNE = 3  ' North East 
  AreaS = 4   ' SOUTH
  AreaNS = 5  ' North South
  AreaSE = 6  ' South East
  AreaNES = 7 ' North East South
  AreaW = 8   ' WEST
  AreaNW = 9  ' North West
  AreaEW = 10 ' East West
  AreaNEW = 11 ' North East West
  AreaW = 12  ' South West
  AreaNSW = 13  ' North South West
  AreaNSE = 14  ' North South East
  ALLAreas = 15  ' North South West East
End Enum
```